# Getting "Uncaught Invariant Violation: Hooks can only be called inside the body..." when import library built with Webpack

Tags: reactjs, webpack, react-hooks, npm-package

In my main app I'm importing the library and then use it as a normal React component. (I am using it in JSX syntax - i.e. `<MyLibrary />` - and not as a function call.)

And the library code - oversimplified - is as follows:

A. src/ndex.js:

```
import React, {useEffect} from "react";

function MyPromosComponent() {
  useEffect(()=>window.scrollTo(0, 0));

  return TEST;
}
export default MyPromosComponent;
```

B. The webpack config I use to bundle it:

```
module.exports = {
    output: {
          path: __dirname,
          filename: "dist/index.js",
          libraryTarget: "umd",
    },
    entry: {
        main: './src/index'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            ... list of the loaders for CSS, SCSS, JS and JSX ...
        ],
    },
}
```

C. And the package.json has:

```
{
    ...
    main: "dist/index",
    ...
    scripts: {
        build: "webpack --mode development --config webpack.config.js"
    },
    ...
}
```

I am getting error on the line I'm using the useEffect hook, in the final output bundle:

```
Object(react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__["useEffect"])(function () {
    return window.scrollTo(0, 0);
});
```

If I remove the hook call - then it works.

Any idea what the problem is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You probably hit the [Duplicate React](https://react.dev/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning#duplicate-react) issue.
- You should use [`externals`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/#externals) configuration for `react` and `react-dom`, `react` and `react-dom` packages should not be bundled along with the library code. We treat them as *peer dependency*.

`webpack.config.js`:

```js
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  mode: 'development',
  entry: './src/index',
  output: {
    filename: '[name].js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    clean: true,
    library: {
      name: 'MyPromosComponent',
      type: 'umd'
    }
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: [
              ['@babel/preset-env', { targets: "defaults" }],
              "@babel/preset-react",
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  externals: {
    react: {
      commonjs: 'react',
      commonjs2: 'react',
      amd: 'React',
      root: 'React',
    },
    'react-dom': {
      commonjs: 'react-dom',
      commonjs2: 'react-dom',
      amd: 'ReactDOM',
      root: 'ReactDOM',
    }
  },
};
```

- If you create the library and try to import the built library from the application. This will trigger the duplicate react issue. Let me demonstrate this issue.

Assume the `myapp` and `react-library` are sibling folders.

E.g.

```
.
├── myapp
│   ├── node_modules
│   ├── package.json
│   ├── package-lock.json
│   ├── public
│   ├── README.md
│   └── src
└── react-library
    ├── dist
    ├── node_modules
    ├── package.json
    ├── package-lock.json
    ├── src
    └── webpack.config.js
```

The `react` and `react-dom` packages should be installed as peer dependencies using `npm install react react-dom --save-peer` command.

`react-library/package.json`:

```json
{
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "name": "react-library",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack"
  },
  "main": "./dist/main.js",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.22.5",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.22.5",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.22.5",
    "babel-loader": "^9.1.2",
    "webpack": "^5.80.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.0.2"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0"
  },
  "files": [
    "./dist/main.js"
  ]
}
```

If you import the React component from `react-library` use the relative path, and the `node_modules` exists in `react-library`. This error will happen.

`myapp/src/App.js`:

```js
import React from 'react';
import MyPromosComponent from '../../react-library'

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <MyPromosComponent />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Let's debug the problem using the approach provided by the official doc.

Add this in `myapp/node_modules/react-dom/index.js`

```js
window.React1 = require('react');
```

`react-library/src/index.js`:

```js
import React, { useEffect } from "react";

// Add this to your component file
require('react-dom');
window.React2 = require('react');
console.log(window.React1 === window.React2); 
function MyPromosComponent() {
  useEffect(() => window.scrollTo(0, 0));
  return <div>my component</div>;
}

export default MyPromosComponent;
```

When I try to render the `App` component, got logs:

```
console.log
    false

      at eval (webpack:/MyPromosComponent/src/index.js?:10:9)
```

As you can see it prints `false` which means there are two Reacts.

**Solution 1.**

As the official doc says, runs `npm link` from `react-library`.

```
/react-library (main) $ npm link ../myapp/node_modules/react
```

Render the `App` component and check the logs:

```
  console.log
    true

      at eval (webpack:/MyPromosComponent/src/index.js?:10:9)
```

It prints `true`, which means it has only one React library loaded at the runtime now.

**Solution 2.**

Publish the `react-library` and install it from the `myapp`. Import it like this:

```js
import MyPromosComponent from 'react-library';
```

**Solution 3.**

Copy the `react-library` folder and exclude `react-library/node_modules` to `myapp/node_modules`, this is some kind of "install". Then import it like solution 2.

Comment: I tried with externals from the very beginning, in different combinations, but couldn't make it work at all. And now, when I set them as you've shown - it magically worked right away :D ... Thanks a lot :)